# My app crashed whenever i add a OnClickListener or a Fragment , here's my code with the OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.android.bloodapp4;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView ourList = findViewById(R.id.theList);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        list.add("Account");
        list.add("Posts");
        list.add("Donations you made");
        ourList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        ourList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent AccIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountActivity.class);
                startActivity(AccIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error are you getting...please share logcat

Comment: Why are you putting `onClickListener` on a `ListView` itself? Try `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: it's a runtime error when i start the app it crashes and i cant share my logcat because the emulator is not working and i cant find my mobile driver to debug the app using my device so their is no logcat :)

Comment: how to write a `setOnItemClickListener` ? @AadityaBrahmbhatt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't create ArrayAdapter truly , you must create a TextView in simple_list_item_1 layout and you must add it on ArrayAdapter constructor. Say textview2 is your textview in simple_list_item_1.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,textview2,list);
```

That will work I believe.

Comment: but i dont want a textview in my activity i want it to be a list and i can click on any item on the list to open another activity

Comment: It will be a list view , think like it is a list of textviews as list items and that is the only way to use list view.

Comment: then i will declare textview2 like it is a list view ?

Comment: You should create a xml file say my_layout.xml then you must add a textview in it.  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.my_layout,textview2,list);  Textview2 is id of textview in my_layout

Comment: Thank you very much ! @NusretÖzateş

Comment: No problem if it works could you make my answer as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your `AccountActivity` in AndroidManifest.xml?

A simple example:

```
<application
....>

    <activity
        android:name=".AccountActivity"/>

</application>
```

Comment: all activities are declared in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Muhammed What's the crash stack trace exactly?

Comment: what is that ? sorry i am a beginner @Sdghasemi

Comment: When your app crashes, the crash will happen somewhere in your code. A stack trace will help you find out the exact location it happened contauning your calling methods sequentially which is called and stack trace. You need to look for the "Logcat" menu usually in the bottom of Android studio and check the logs when the crash happens filtered in "Error". this is how you can find your crash stack trace. [More info](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces)